# Secure way to protect an object in c++

Tags: c++, security

I'm planning on trying to create something really secure and I want to protect it from memory attack (like looking at a specific adress to get an Object in a program (Like how cheater gets information from entities in CS:GO))

Can someone know how the New operator works on c++ and if it protects whats created from this kind of attack ?

And if possible how to protect from this kind of attack.

Comment: The new operator has no such protection at all.

Comment: I say is not possible to 100% prevent attacks of this kind. If it was companies with hundreds of programmers working on this task would have accomplished it for their software making cheat engines not work at all.

Comment: Attach debugger - own program.

Comment: This is an arms race between cheaters/hackers and developers which the developer will always lose if the software is hosted by the attacker. The program has to run, and the host has fully access to the system to inspect what the program is doing and inspect the binary to figure out how it works. There isn't really anything you can do that completely keeps out a determined attacker if the application is locally hosted on their system and if you still want the application to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to completely prevent something like this happening, however you can it make it more difficult (for example by randomizing the memory locations). Also a relevent link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization.